# Can I deploy dependecies to public maven central?

Tags: java, maven

Ok, I have searched for a long time but, I can not see it clear. Can I or not deploy my dependencies in maven central? If yes...

1. [This post](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html) is not sufficient, What is the maven central deploy url?
2. I need a user to deploy? If yes, How can I create a user to deploy?
3. Can I deploy private dependencies?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by private dependencies?

Comment: @khmarbaise dependencies that only authenticated users can access

Comment: What do you mean by `authenticated users can access` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, something like ftp, you need to have a user and password to access the dependency

Comment: No does not exist nor does it make sense in Maven Central.

Answer (score 4):

You can deploy your artifacts into Maven Central. The requirements are described here:

http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html

Here you can go through and request to Maven Central:

http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html